# XMLHttpRequests clogging/pending in Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, browser

If I have a lot of active layers and eg. zooom in and out, dozens of tile xmlhttprequests are sent. This causes a problem in most browsers, clogging it so to speak, and leaving the map blank and dozens of Pending resource requests in Network Console (in eg. Chrome).

Any known work-around for this issue? I'm creating a map with dozens of layers for a client, and with some activity on the map (zoom, adding lots of layers simultaneously, etc), this issue will appear.

What is needed, I believe, is some internal queue in Leaflet.js, as the queue in eg. Chrome browser is buggy.

Comment: This is due to the browsers not being able to handle more than n requests simultaneously (I believe it's six per remote server, and 16 in total).  That's why you see map-servers hosting tiles from a.mapbox.com, b.mapbox.com etc.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the problem: do you need to switch each layer individually? Instead you could merge some layers to avoid to query `n tiles * n layers`. [This article](http://mapbrief.com/2013/02/05/why-map-portals-dont-work-part-i/) may help you to change your viewpoint.

If you don't change your viewpoint,

You can use WMS with an intermediate tile cache to keep decent performances. Why I recommend WMS although most people will say `WMS is dead!`? It's simply because you can query in one WMS call more than one layer and always return one image instead of a tile for each layer of information. You will hence only query `n tiles * one image layer embedding multiple informations`. You can look at this [WMS Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms#lwmssource) after you made your WMS server.

You can also make tiles compositing if you are stuck with tiles layers you don't control using [TileStache "Pixel sandwich"](http://tilestache.org/doc/#sandwich-provider) (as long as you are allowed to as it's could be considered as tiles request usage cheat: it's a cache mecanism)